# Setting Multiple Cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Thanks for helping with this.

I have a script that checks logins and then sets some cookies. There are 4 cookies that are being set, (later I will probably move some to server session but for now I am using cookies.

The issue that I am having is that only the first 2 of the 4 are being set before the rest of the script is being executed. Can anyone see why?

```
// If there is a row, and only 1 row, then the details are correct. Set the cookie and re-direct
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

            setcookie('user_id', $row['User_ID'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
            setcookie('user_name',  $row['UserName'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
            setcookie('access_Level', $row['Access_Level'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
            setcookie('db_con', $row['Db_Con'], time()+ (60*15),"/");

            $home_url = $link . "application/views/Dashboard.php";
            header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

Comment: Also, if the value you're setting the cookie to is empty or null, it will not create the cookie.

Comment: @Jared The two that ARE working are user_id and user_name. The information from the database is being received (and can be echo'd) @ Michael, Access level is simply a number of 1 to 5 that allows users to control abilities of other members of their profiles, but I will move a lot of these to session as I dont need any persistance really.

Comment: How are you checking to determine they are being set or not? Are you checking in the browser? For instance, Firefox lets you see the cookies for a page by right-clicking on the page, `View Page Info`, `Security` tab, `View Cookies` button. The reason I say this is that the `access_Level` key does not match the other key casing (all lowercase initial letters). So you might be looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Yeah I am checking using Firefox and Chrome, Both of which show the first two but not the last two. Also my application cannot access them when necessary. good catch on the casing tho, Although I haven't implemented the access_level thing, it should be the same casing.

Comment: Late to the game here, but I'm hoping you have learned to store these inside the session and NOT in cookies where I can manipulate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
<?php

$row = array(
    'User_ID' => '1',
    'UserName' => '1',
    'Access_Level' => '1',
    'Db_Con' => '1'
);

setcookie('user_id', $row['User_ID'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
setcookie('user_name',  $row['UserName'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
setcookie('access_Level', $row['Access_Level'], time()+ (60*15),"/");
setcookie('db_con', $row['Db_Con'], time()+ (60*15),"/");

// This will not be set, and the cookie is not created.
setcookie('db_con2', $row['Db_Con2'], time()+ (60*15),"/");

?>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/setcookie.php

In Firefox, I check to see the cookies for a page by right-clicking on the page, `View Page Info`, `Security` tab, `View Cookies` button. All four cookies show up on that page in my browser. The last one does not (since it is has no value).

I'm thinking your column names are not spelled/capitalized correctly, or some other issue, and that `$row['Access_Level']` and `$row['Db_Con']` are empty columns in your result.

Comment: Seems like the most likely answer, but they are spelled the same, and the database also has entries for those two rows... I will keep debugging along these lines.

Comment: I have no idea how i did it!  but I moved the "Db_Con" to another table (as I was going to do this anyway) and re-wrote the query to include an inner join and hey presto the whole thing works... must have been a typo somewhere that I just cannot see!!!

Comment: My guess is that what `$row` had in it for that column_name was empty/null, meaning the query was not returning what you thought it was (irregardless of what was in the database).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the obvious question: Have you tried copying the variables you're saving to cookies, and pasting them into a `print_r()` statement, so you can prove that they have the values you expect. It's possible you made a typo or incorrect capitalisation, or something similar.

The next thing to check are the values in these variables. You haven't specified the possible values for `Access_Level` and `Db_Con`, but if they are set to `false` or blank, then the cookie will be cleared, rather than being set to that value. This is unlikely to be what you want.

If that's not the problem, another possible issue (though I doubt it in this case) is total length of your cookies. A site may only serve a maximum of 4K in its cookie string. If you're using UTF-8 encoding (which is recommended) this means only about a thousand characters, including all the field names and formatting of the cookie string, as well as the values. Cookies beyond that length will not be saved. It doesn't look like that's your problem here, but I guess it's possible you're serving other cookies as well as these four, which could be tipping the balance.

I would also strongly recommend not using cookies for the sorts of data you're using it for here.

It is important to know that cookies are a highly insecure means of storing data. They can be spied on by third parties, and are easily tampered with. If your site is relying on `Access_Level` to be accurate in subsequent page loads and is using it to decide whether or not to grant access to certain pages, then you have given your site a *massive* security hole.

Secondly, Cookies are inefficient. The entire cookie string is sent in both directions for every single request made to the server. This includes graphics and other files which aren't able to actually affect them. So if a page has a lot of images, stylesheets and javascript files that it loads, then you'll be sending all your cookies up and down the wire possibly dozens of times every time the user goes to a new page.

I recommend using PHP sessions instead. Granted they also use a cookie, but it doesn't contain any data that can easily be tampered with, and it is only a single cookie variable, so it minimises both these issues. It's also extremely easy to use.

Hope that helps.