# Cookies not saved from the fourth column data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just building a simple todo-list. I built the checkboxes, which save as cookies so when next time users can see the checkboxes checked.
A part of my code:

```php
//this code is in a table which shows checkboxes in each row.
//tasks is the query which selects all from the database
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="checksubmit" name="checksubmit">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="tick"><div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="arraycheck[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
                <?php
                if ((((isset($_POST['arraycheck'])) && (in_array($row['id'], $_POST['arraycheck'])))) || (isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']]))) {
                    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']])) {
                        setcookie ($row['id'],"checked='checked'",time()+3600000);
                    }
                }
                if ((isset($_POST['button-submit'])) && (!in_array($row['id'], $_POST['arraycheck']))) {
                    setcookie ($row['id'],"",time()-3600);
                }

                 echo $_COOKIE[$row['id']];
                ?>>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="check<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

The code work just fine! Checkboxes are saved by cookies.
**BUT THE PROBLEM:** Only the first four rows worked, from the fifth row, everything didn't worked. What a weird error!

Comment: cookies have limits about how much data you can put on. Maybe that is your problem

Comment: thanks for commenting! so how can i resolve this

Comment: but the weird thing is when I try to check the 6th checkbox of the 6th row for example, it won't work either

Comment: If your problem is that (you have to be sure about that) there are not many things you can do. Write less data.

Comment: check if this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726522/setting-multiple-cookies-in-php

Comment: it won't worked on the >4th row even there are no cookies at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

- The *setcookie()* calls won't work at all and will fail with a "headers already sent" warning. This is the main reason why your code is not working.
- Your are using *tr* without having a *table*. If you have a *table* outside of the *form* I think this is not valid.
- At least in the code you posted the *form* is not closed.
- This line produces a "undefined offset" warning if the cookie is not set:

  echo $_COOKIE[$row['id']];

You should also indent your code because then you can see mistakes better.
And if not already done add this to the beginning to see errors and warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: this is just a part of my code, I already have table. By the way, thanks for answering, could you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The full code:

```php
 <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
               <tr>
                  <th>STT</th>
                  <th>Lời nhắc</th>
                  <th style="width: 50px;">Xong?</th>
                  <th style="width: 50px;">Ảnh</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="checksubmit" name="checksubmit">
               <?php $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
               <tr>
                  <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
                  <td class="task"> <?php if(isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']])) {echo '<span style="color:gray;"><strike>';} echo $row['task']; if(isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']])) {echo '</strike></span>';} ?> </td>


                  <td class="tick"><div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input  type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="arraycheck[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" 
        <?php  
            if((((isset($_POST['arraycheck'])) && (in_array($row['id'], $_POST['arraycheck'])))) || (isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']]))) {
                if(!isset($_COOKIE[$row['id']])) {
                    setcookie ($row['id'],"checked='checked'",time()+3600000);   }
            }
            if  ((isset($_POST['button-submit'])) && (!in_array($row['id'], $_POST['arraycheck']))) {
                        setcookie ($row['id'],"",time()-3600);  
                } 



         echo $_COOKIE[$row['id']];    

        ?>>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="check<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></label>
  </div></td>

  <td><?php if (!empty($row['image'])) { ?> <a href="view.php?idimg=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-image"></i></a> <?php } ?></td>
               </tr>
               <?php $i++; } ?> 
               <tr> 
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input type="submit" value="Lưu" class="btn btn-primary" name="button-submit">
               </form></td>
               </tr>

            </tbody>

         </table>
```